# Error : expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

I am working on pre processing the data for "Job Description" column which contains text data format. I have created a dataframe and trying to apply a function to pre process the data, but getting the error as "expected string or bytes-like object" when applying function to the column in data frame. Please refer my code below and help.

```
####################################################    
#Function to pre process the data    
def clean_text(text):
        """
        Applies some pre-processing on the given text.

        Steps :
        - Removing HTML tags
        - Removing punctuation
        - Lowering text
        """

        # remove HTML tags
        text = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', text)

        # remove the characters [\], ['] and ["]
        text = re.sub(r"\\", "", text)    
        text = re.sub(r"\'", "", text)    
        text = re.sub(r"\"", "", text)    

        # convert text to lowercase
        text = text.strip().lower()

        #replace all numbers with empty spaces
        text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]",  # Search for all non-letters
                              " ",          # Replace all non-letters with spaces
                              str(text))

        # replace punctuation characters with spaces
        filters='!"\'#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n'
        translate_dict = dict((c, " ") for c in filters)
        translate_map = str.maketrans(translate_dict)
        text = text.translate(translate_map)

        return text
#############################################################     
#To apply "Clean_text" function to job_description column in data frame        
df['jobnew']=df['job_description'].apply(clean_text)
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-33-c15402ac31ba> in <module>()
        ----> 1 df['jobnew']=df['job_description'].apply(clean_text)

        ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
           3192             else:
           3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
        -> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
           3195 
           3196         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

        pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

        <ipython-input-30-5f24dbf9d559> in clean_text(text)
             10 
             11     # remove HTML tags
        ---> 12     text = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', text)
             13 
             14     # remove the characters [\], ['] and ["]

        ~\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
            190     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
            191     a replacement string to be used."""
        --> 192     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
            193 
            194 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

        TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `re.sub` is telling you that you called it with something (the argument `text`) that is not a string. Since it is invoked by calling `apply` on the contents of `df['job_description']`, it is clear that the problem must be in how you created this data frame... and you don't show that part of your code.

Construct your dataframe so that this column only contains strings, and your program will run without error for at least a few more lines.